# How to get the assigned variable name of a set javascript 'class'

Tags: javascript, class

If I assign

```
displayUL = new displayListMaker({{ $displays }});
```

How do I get the variable displayUL if this is even possible

```
var displayListMaker = function(displays){
```

like

```
this.self = wantthevariable
```

so I can generate html that calls itself

```
return '<a onclick="'+this.self+'.callAFunc(withdata)">call myself :)</a>'
```

Comment: Can you try another explanation? At the moment I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Not possible. There could be multiple references. Why do you need this? [What is the XY Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @RobH: `displayListMaker` is a constructor function, which creates some HTML that includes an inline `onclick` handler attribute that needs to reference the object created from the constructor. So OP wants to know how to reference the newly created object from within the handler attribute, and thinks an implicitly created reference to the eventual variable that will hold the object is the solution.

Comment: Exactly, I'm trying to make a Unorderd List with clickable Listitems that should push its id to an array inside the class. So that I can like say displayUL.retrieveSelectedIds(), maybe I should use backbone but it seems to much for what I need right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the name of the variable that will ultimately reference an object inside the constructor because there could eventually be multiple references to the same object, so how could it know which to use?

If this is for an inline handler attribute, then having the name of the local variable won't matter anyway since the handler body is executed in the global variable scope.

---

If the `displayUL` variable is global, one solution could be to pass the name of the global to the constructor, and have it add the global variable there, and code the name into the string.

```
new displayListMaker($displays, "displayUL");

var displayListMaker = function(displays, name) {
    window[name] = displays;

    '<a onclick="' + name + '.callAFunc(withdata)">call myself :)</a>'
    // ...and so on
```

---

Though I'd venture a guess that your issue is entire around your `onclick="..."` attribute. Creating the DOM element directly and using an `elem.onclick = func...` property, while keeping a closure reference to the object is probably what you really need.

```
new displayListMaker($displays);

var displayListMaker = function(displays, name) {
    var that = this;

    var elem = document.createElement("a")
    elem.innerHTML = "call myself :)"

    elem.onclick = function() {
        that.callAFunc(withdata);
    }
    // ...and so on
```